# What is the best, safest way to create another partition after installation Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, disk

I've already installed Ubuntu 20.04, but I did not make any separate partitions beside the one the operating system is installed on.

Now I would like to create a new partition, as **safely** and simply as possible. Please excuse me I am brand new in Linux(Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: The safest way is to add a new drive and put the partition in that drive. But if you cannot or it would be awkward to add a new drive it is not the best way. Editing partitions is always risky, but OK, if you have a recent backup of everything that you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: The word "safely" implies that you have your data backed up before editing partitions. I'd recommend to make use of your installer-USB (Try without installing)and run Gparted from there.

Comment: Any changes to a partition table cannot be deemed *safe* but *risky* in my opinion; so ensure you have backups before you start. The only thing you can do is not use it during change - why you use *live* media as already outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a new install you hopefully dont have a lot of precious data on it, but go ahead and make a backup anyway..

If you really mean partition, and not volume, you should be able to just fire up gparted and shrink the existing partition (which will shrink the filesystem for you too), then create a new partition in the new free space.

If you cant do this, its still fairly simple. Its not massively risky, but you'll want that backup we talked about:

1. shrink the filesystem - resize2fs can help you here
2. shrink the partition to just a bit bigger than the new fs size
3. grow the filesystem to the new partition size
4. make a new partition in the new space

Comment: Thank You for Your Time and advice;-) Best regards !